# CALayer NSImage contents not choosing correct representation

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, calayer, nsimage

I am setting `NSImages` to the contents of several `CALayers`. All of these images have 4 reps, **1x, 2x, 5x and 10x**. 3 of these images scale seemingly fine when I set the contentsScale when my view changes it's `backingScaleFactor` but one of them seems to always choose the **1x** representation no matter what I do. Here are my images logged into console:

```
<NSImage 0x1019cea60 Size={20, 24} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0db60 Size={20, 24} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=20x24 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0c8e0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0ec90 Size={20, 24} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=40x48 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0dbd0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0fdb0 Size={20, 24} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=100x120 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0ed00",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a10ef0 Size={20, 24} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=200x240 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0fcb0"
)>
<NSImage 0x1001faa90 Size={28, 320} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a06240 Size={28, 320} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=28x320 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a05230",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a07370 Size={28, 320} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=56x640 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a062d0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a08490 Size={28, 320} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=140x1600 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a07400",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a095c0 Size={28, 320} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=280x3200 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a08390"
)>
<NSImage 0x10052e790 Size={28, 40} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a01d10 Size={28, 40} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=28x40 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a005d0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a02de0 Size={28, 40} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=56x80 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a01da0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a03f00 Size={28, 40} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=140x200 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a02fa0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a05080 Size={28, 40} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=280x400 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a040c0"
)>
<NSImage 0x101bbfc40 Size={28, 600} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0a760 Size={28, 600} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=28x600 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a094f0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0b890 Size={28, 600} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=56x1200 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0a7f0",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0ba60 Size={28, 600} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=140x3000 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0ab10",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x101a0c9b0 Size={28, 600} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=280x6000 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101a0b920"
)>
```

The third one (28 x 40) is always being drawn at 1x. Here is the code I use to set the scale factor:

```
- (void)viewDidChangeBackingProperties {
    [super viewDidChangeBackingProperties];
    self.layer.contentsScale       = self.window.backingScaleFactor;
    self.otherLayer.contentsScale  = self.window.backingScaleFactor;

    self.otherLayer.contents = self.image;
}
```

I set the layer contents to image again because in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188500/automatic-scaling-of-multipage-tiff-nsimage-in-a-calayer) it was established that the `CALayer` chooses the best representation of the `NSImage` when it draws and it would need to be set again.

I ran the new `-recommendedLayerContentsScale:` method on all of my images and they all returned 2.0 when given 2.0 except for the one that is not scaling correctly.

EDIT: I wrote the broken image to a file and then opened made a new `NSImage` with -`initWithContentsOfFile` in a different app and I put it in an `NSImageView` and the problem persists! It works with one of the images that were working though. Clearly something is wrong with Apple's image choosing code.